# Debugging class library - Target App "out of memory"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging, add-in, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to build and add-in for Enterprise Architect. 
To test I set the "external program" to the correct path to EA, and then, when it's starting debugging and EA is loading, EA go out of memory and exit.

It's looks like Visual Studio (2013) limit memory size of external program, or something else. Is there a way to increase this memory?

Another info: The workaround I found is attach to the process after load manually EA, but is very comfortable press F5.

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a6542cef-d38b-4889-93b9-ba1d5334e4a0/start-external-program-no-longer-works-in-vs2003-once-20-framework-installed?forum=vbide for a possible cause.  Although the .NET Framework versions in the article are older, in general it indicates that the target version of .NET Framework of the application being different from your application might be the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post](http://www.sparxsystems.com/cgi-bin/yabb/YaBB.cgi?num=1430262166/2#2) on the EA Forum this would be VS 2013 specific issue.

I try to test as my add-ins as much as possible without actually running them as an add-in. I developed as small test application for this purpose. Some explanation about that in this post: [Testing and debugging your Enterprise Architect add-in](http://bellekens.com/2011/02/08/testing-and-debugging-your-enterprise-architect-csharp-add-in/)

For the features I can't test with the test tool I just start EA manually and then attach to the ea.exe process.

Comment: Thanks @geert. I opened my project in VS2010 and I confirmed the issue. The EA was loaded sucessfully.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2015/07/02/debugging-c-addins-with-enterprise-architect-12-and-visual-studio-2013/) from LieberLieber:

1. Go to Tools → Options
2. Under Debugging → General
3. Select the option "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"

I tested it with Visual Studio 2015 and it works.

I find that attaching to the process is a step back since you won't be able to debug on the EA_Connect Event or other events that are executed too fast to catch in debugging.